# select more than one count in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Is it possible in MySQL to do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as totalcount, 
       COUNT(*) WHERE foo IS NULL as conditional_count 
  FROM baz
```

i.e. get two counts, one of everything, and one of things matching a WHERE clause, in a single select?

Comment: it should be like this `SELECT COUNT(*) as totalcount, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE foo IS NULL) as conditional_count 
  FROM baz` this is a single query but with subquery inside

Comment: @skowron-line  Please post as an answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This would work if your database supports the CASE WHEN statement, otherwise you'll still get the basic idea.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
       SUM(CASE WHEN FOO IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT_CONDITIONAL
  FROM baz
```

Comment: Marked this as best because I tried it and it worked. The sub-select method from skowron-line looked good too but doesn't work with my version of MySQL, it seems.

Answer (score 2):

it should be like this `SELECT COUNT(*) as totalcount, (SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE foo IS NULL) as conditional_count FROM baz` this is a single query but with subquery inside

Comment: Looks good but doesn't work with MySQL server 5.0.37 which is what I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT count(*) as totalcount, 
(select COUNT(*) FROM baz WHERE foo IS NULL)
as conditional_count FROM baz;

i can't place star(*) between the count brackets!!!
I put it, but i can't display it.

Answer (score 0):

try with UNION ( not tested )

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as totalcount FROM baz
UNION
SELECT  COUNT(*) WHERE foo IS NULL as conditional_count FROM baz
```

Comment: This would return 2 records with 1 field instead of 1 record with 2 fields

Comment: This gives you two rows with one column called `totalcount`.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think this is possible.  I reckon you would need two queries.

```
Select count(*) from baz

Select count(foo) from baz where foo is null
```